# Sparql : Dealing with '/' symbol

Tags: sparql, protege

How can I use / in select sparql select ?first/object, I what name of column in result to be first/object

Comment: the grammar for var names is online: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rVARNAME

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. '/' is not a legal character in a SPARQL variable name.

As @UninformedUser mentioned in their comment, you can see the full range of legal variable names by looking at the SPARQL grammar: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rVARNAME .